# solr PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory working unexpectedly

Tags: regex, search, solr

I am relatively new to Solr so please forgive me if I'm missing something obvious.  I have an application that allows users to search for musical artists.  The indexing comes from a read-only database with correct spellings so on the index side I have it figured out.

On the query side however I need to anticipate various spelling errors/differences and want to help solr find those instances.  From our old home-grown search solution, I have a list of regex's and the artists they apply to.  When I was trying to translate those to solr using the PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory, I noticed that some worked perfectly, while others didn't work at all ... with seeming no rhyme nor reason between them.

For example:

```
<charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="em[ei]n[ei]m" replacement="Eminem"/>
```

accurately captures the common misspellings of Eminem.  But for the band 311:

```
<charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="[Tt]hree [Ee]leven" replacement="311"/>
```

Does not work.  Another example is Nine Inch Nails:

```
<charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="((nine|9).*inch.*nails\b)|(n\.? ?i\.? ?n\.?\b)" replacement="Nine Inch Nails"/>
```

works perfectly for finding the most common patterns for the band's name.  But for Eve 6:

```
       <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="[Ee]ve.{0,4}([Ss]ix|6)" replacement="Eve 6"/>
```

Is there something fundamental I'm missing on the usage of this filter?  I've tried a number of variations on the regex's I've mentioned above (even going so far as using literals like 'three eleven'), but still with no success.  I've tried making the filter in question the only PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory in the analyzer.  I also know for sure that these items are in the index correctly because when I search for the correct spelling it returns the proper results.

Any suggestions?

Snowdall

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the problem is not with your Char Factory, but with what comes after all, specifically the tokenizer. If you use standard tokenizer, it will get rid of the numbers you have just put into your stream. If you don't need the text to be split into tokens, you could look at [KeywordTokenizerFactory](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory) instead.

In general, the best way to troubleshoot this in Solr 4+ is the Analysis screen in the Admin WebUI. It allows you to enter your text against particular field type and see what happens with it after each component in the analysis chain.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the SynonymFilter for the kind of application you describe.  It allows you to provide an external file where you list words and their synonyms, like:

```
eminem <=> emenem
nine <=> 9
```

If you precede this with a LowerCaseFilter, you won't have to fuss about case normalization in your synonyms.  You should be able to handle the 311 case too as long as you don't tokenize (ie use a KeywordTokenizer as Alexander Rafalovitch suggested).